# I2C transmission gate transistors

Tags: i2c, pullup, usb-pd, transmission-gate

I have been looking at a design that uses [DMN31D5UDJ-7](https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/115/DIOD_S_A0004567166_1-2542680.pdf)s for gating I2C signals that are connected to 4.7 kΩ pull-ups to VIO = 1.8 V.

[image]

I was wondering if I could replace these transistors with [BSS138PS](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BSS138PS.pdf)s since I already have them in the design, and I don't want many different transistors for assembly.

My only concern about the BSS138PS compared to the DMN31D5UDJ-7 is that it has a higher V<sub>GS(th)</sub>:

**BSS138PS**:
V<sub>GS(th)</sub>: min: 0.9 V, max: 1.5 V
**DMN31D5UDJ-7**:
V<sub>GS(th)</sub>: min: 0.4 V, max: 1 V

Can I make this replacement?

This I2C is between a [KB8010](https://www.kandou.com/assets/downloads/product_briefs/KA-000250-PB.pdf) re-timer and a [CYPD6227](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-EZ-PD_CCG6DF_CCG6SF_USB_Type-C_Port_Controller-DataSheet-v10_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0ee8e2c571be) USB PD controller.

It looks like we have a one side level shifter from 3.3 V to 1.8 V from the HOST_TWI signals (PD controller side from the left) towards the re-timer (right side) which means the only scenario I can think of is that the PD controller is the master and the re-timer is the slave, and it can't be the opposite, since we don't have a bi-directional level shifter, am I right?

From the CYPD6227 datasheet,  I2C_SCL_SCB3/P3.2 and I2C_SDA_SCB3/P3.1 to which HOST_TWI.SDA/SCL are connected, are GPIOs that can have an internal PU, and their input voltage level is: min = -0.5 V, max = VDDIO + 0.5 V where VDDIO is 3.3 V.

[image]

Comment: That circuit is not a gating the I2C signals. I2C is a bi-directional bus and that is a bi-directional level shifter.

Comment: O.K, please allow me to put the rest of the question aside for someone to answer. hopefully. 
Apparently I have a conceptual misunderstanding of this basic circuit, that has N-MOSFET and PU, to my understanding, it can can level shift high voltage to low voltage, but it can't do the opposite thing, Is that alright?

Comment: _"to my understanding, it can can level shift high voltage to low voltage, but it can't do the opposite thing"_ That's wrong, you can level-shift in both directions. You just need to add pull-ups on both sides. Also see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/555631/understanding-how-this-bi-directional-logic-level-shift-works

Comment: O.K, I understand, but giving only the circuit above, without PU on the other side, you can't level-shift both directions. I'm trying to check if the other side (CYPD6227) has internal PU's on the I2C. from datasheet this pin is GPIO, and it can have PU, so maybe the reference i'm looking at implemented the PU internally.

Comment: I²C would not work at all without pull-ups at the HOST_TWI side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit requires that the transistors switch with a gate-to-source voltage of V<sub>IO</sub> = 1.8 V.

The BSS138PS guarantees switching only for 5 V (this is the test condition for R<sub>DS(on)</sub>). And the lowest gate voltage for which typical (not even guaranteed) values are shown in figures 6/8 is 2 V. And figure 9 shows that you should not try anything below or near 2 V:

[image: BSS138PS RDSon vs. VGS]

The DMN31D5UDJ is guaranteed to work at 1.8 V or lower (you can also use any other MOSFET with such a specification):

[image: DMN31D5UDJ on characteristics]

Comment: what do you mean the test condition? where is this written in datasheet?
and for 5V you mean the VG or VGS?

Comment: The test condition is marked in red. A MOSFET has no ground pin, so the gate voltage is usually measured against source, i.e., VG = VGS.

Comment: Did you say that "The BSS138PS guarantees switching only for 5 V " because in the RDS_ON Table we have 50mA for VGS = 5V? 
Why doesn't 4V for example 4V guarantee switching? from the graph you shared we can see clearly that for 4V we have RDS_ON around 1 Ohm (for T_AMP = 25 Celsius)

Comment: I suppose you mean to say it's wasn't in the Test Condition, but theoretically in the graph it *could* work for 4V. since the graph they show is also a real test.

Comment: The graph shows typical values, which are not guaranteed.